# Bash Script - Get result of `(.*)` (dot star) in grep regex

Tags: shell-script, grep, regular-expression

Let's say I have the following JSON string in a Bash script variable, `DATA`:

```
{
    "id": 10,
    "name": "Person 1",
    "note": "This is a test"
}
```

I need to get the value of the `name` field. I have used `grep` like this:

```
NAME=$(echo "$DATA" | grep -E "\"name\": \"(.*)\"")
```

However, this returns `"name": "Person 1"`. I need `Person 1`. How can I get the result of just the `(.*)`?

Comment: A more general answer: If the data was line based (**not json**), then you would use `sed`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this easily with `jq`:

```
$ DATA='{
    "id": 10,
    "name": "Person 1",
    "note": "This is a test"
}'
$ jq -r '.name' <<<"$DATA"
Person 1
```

In general, it's best to avoid regex for parsing structured data such as html, json, and yaml.

To accomplish this with grep, you need to use PCRE to leverage look-aheads and look-behinds:

```
$ echo $DATA | grep -Po '(?<="name": ").*(?=")'
Person 1
```

Comment: `jq` makes things a lot easier. Thank you so much! I'll accept the answer after the 10 minute timer